# MySQL Column name defined by php variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, variables

Is it possible to CREATE a table in mysql with the the Column names being defined as php variables?

I have an array called $stretch[];

It is an array of years from one point to another eg: 2005-2020.

I would like to assign this array as column names for the database columns within the MySQL DB.

A simple question I know. But I cant seem to find an answer anywhere within the site.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Have you looked up the syntax for creating a table in MySQL?  How to execute a command against MySQL from PHP?  How to build a string from your values?  Where specifically are you stuck?  It's unlikely that you'll find another example of the *exact* code you'd need for your custom scenario, but each of the components to build that code are readily available.

Comment: It more the array im stuck on. I know how to create a table and i know i can define columns with variables. Im just not sure how to use an array in the same way.

Comment: It is possible but I'm wondering why you'd want to do that. It could also be prone to injection.

Comment: what would you suggest?

Comment: its a temporary SESSION table that will be destroyed with the session.

Comment: It'd be best to edit your question so that it contains what the array is and what you tried. That way, we'd be able to help you more by seeing if something went wrong somewhere. Using sessions could be an issue here also.

Comment: can you tell me why? I would use the session as a unique id timestamp for the table name destroy it when the session destroys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `foreach` over the array and build a string, or assuming they are the same type and length (which is important to know):

```
$columns = implode(" VARCHAR(255),", $stretch) . " VARCHAR(255)";

// if numeric column names need to be escaped use backticks
$columns = "`" . implode("` VARCHAR(255), `", $stretch) . "` VARCHAR(255)";

$query   = "CREATE TABLE table_name ($columns)";
```

Yields something like:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (2020 VARCHAR(255),2021 VARCHAR(255))
```

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (`2020` VARCHAR(255), `2021` VARCHAR(255))
```

Comment: Columns names cannot be all integers unless they're escaped, last I remember and it's really bad design, IMHO.

Comment: Ok. So that would create the amount of columns required aswell? Thank you so much for helo btw. –

Comment: Thanks @FunkFortyNiner edited...